# Group Based Administrators can't see Service Provider configurations

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Our installation of wso2 Identity Server 5.7.1 has multiple service providers configured. The built-in admin set all of these up. We defined a group in the user-mgt.xml that is in the Primary store that has admins. These admins can sign-in as Administrators, but they cannot see the Service Providers configured by the built-in administrator account. How can the other administrators see all the Service Provider configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a corresponding role for each SP. The users in that role can view and update the SP. By default, only the owner of the SP is assigned to that role. But you can add others to it so that they also get access to the SP.